# retrieve images from .NET web service stored on azure like blob

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, azure

Im trying to figure out how to retrieve images from a web service that is connected to azure thats has the images stored as blob.. i just want to be pointed in the right direction, sure if some one have a code example that will be really helpful aswell!

I have not tried any code yet just used google, youtube to find a good example... but no luck.. :/

I can store the images in a folder with the web service if that is easier?

Comment: No one that can help?? :)

Comment: Your question is fairly unclear. I don't understand the issue you're having. You should edit your question to explain the specific issue you're struggling with. Also: You posted a comment wondering why nobody's answering you, **only one hour after posting your question.** Maybe focus on improving the question, to get responses.

Answer (score 0):

Blobs are accessible using standard URLs. You may need a Shared Access Signature to access the file on a private blob.

I can point you in this direction:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1/

Your service should do this (if I understand your need):

1. Create an output stream
2. Create in an input stream to a blob object and accessed using a SAS
3. Connect output stream with input stream

There are plenty of examples around for doing this...